# Is there a way to not rebuild cordova applications when adding a new plugin?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

The title is self-explanatory but I will try to explain better.

I have a Cordova app for Android and iOS and I want to add a new plugin without the need to use the command `cordova build [insert your platform here]` because that command builds all the application and removes the current code and sets the project like the beginning.

How I can add plugins without having to backup all the existing project, build the platform and copy again the code with the plugins properly added?

Comment: What do you mean by `removes the current code and sets the project like the beginning` ? You can't add a plugin without rebuilding the app...

Comment: @Riron so, I can't add a plugin without rebuilding the app, no? Something like ````update ios````.

Comment: As a plugin use native code (Java or Obj-C for example), it has to be re-build. So no, you can't...